# How can I get my reactjs web application hosted within a WebView2 control authenticate into Okta using Windows login?

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect, okta

I have a reactjs application that correctly authenticates with Okta using the redux-oidc and oidc-client npm packages, and when it is run in a browser it automatically authenticates using the windows login credentials. My web application is being displayed within a WebView2 control in a c# .net 5 WinForms application, however Okta prompts the user to login with their username/password rather than using the windows login credentials. Does anyone know how I can get Okta to use the windows login?

My c# code to add the WebView2 control:

```cs
var userDataFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyDesktopApp");
            var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolder);

            _webViewHost = new WebView2
            {
                Visible = true,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            await _webViewHost.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Okta tenant should be configured to use Desktop SSO to be able to achieve that. Please check [Okta documentation](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/ad-desktop-sso-main.htm) for one of the methods to implement that. Agentless DSSO is a newer one and doesn't require additional infrastructure.